# Automatically switch to Cyrillic in Insert Mode in Vim

Tags: linux, vim, debian

Is it possible to make Vim switch to Cyrillic keyboard layout when I go to Insert Mode, then switch back to English for Command Mode (perhaps by executing `setxkbmap`)?

Currently, I use it to edit a document written in Cyrillic, and it's getting tiring having to constantly press Alt+Shift.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `langmap` option is meant to solve exactly those issues. From `:help 'langmap'`:

```
This option allows switching your keyboard into a special language
mode.  When you are typing text in Insert mode the characters are
inserted directly.  When in command mode the 'langmap' option takes
care of translating these special characters to the original meaning
of the key.  This means you don't have to change the keyboard mode to
be able to execute Normal mode commands.
```

Comment: I found http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_Vim_key_bindings_while_typing_non-latin1_text, where they say langmap doesn't work for `utf8` locale - only for `cp1251` and `koi8-r`. Is what they're saying correct?

Comment: I can't say. I only had a brief encounter with it a long while ago. You'll have to test for yourself but the greek example seems encouraging.

Comment: I am pretty sure this feature functions fine in utf-8 if configured properly. That is the encoding most people use Vim in. I'm sure somebody would have complained or fixed it by now if keymaps just didn't work.